# Saving a file made in PS with .ico extension makes it useless

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, cs6, favicon

I tried designing a small `32px x 32px` pixel file in Photoshop CS6 to make a favicon for my website. But saving it as an `.ico` file makes it an unprocessable image and could not be used. But when I designed the same using paint and saved it as an `.ico` file there in paint, the image worked. Can I know why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of the 'why', but I know how to solve it – I had the same problem but just discovered [**Real favicon generator**](http://realfavicongenerator.net/) via this thread: 
**[StackOverflow: best practice for favicons 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029342/favicons-best-practice-for-2013)** and it does the job perfectly!

You just need to throw in a high-res version of your icon and it generates all the icons you need (for mobile and tablet as well as desktop).

Comment: wow! Thank you this has really been useful. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use CS5 most of the time, and if I recall correctly, there is no native ICO export. I've used this plugin for years now: [**Telegraphics plugins**](http://www.telegraphics.com.au/sw/)